# cannot upload to PYPI with twine

Tags: gitlab, pypi, twine

> $ TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token $ TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} $
> docker exec cppbuilder python3 -m twine upload -u ${TWINE_USERNAME} -p
> ${TWINE_PASSWORD} --repository
> ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi
> /src_vol/build --verbose ERROR    InvalidConfiguration: Missing
>
> 'https://mytech.com/api/v4/projects/547/packages/pypi'
> section from ~/.pypirc.
> More info: https://packaging.python.org/specifications/pypirc/          Cleaning
> up project directory and file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed:
> exit status 1

I built cpp package inside docker container, that steps works, and I have built package in the container folder /src_vol/build. When I try to use twine to upload this package to GITLAB PYPI, I am getting the error.

Any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by myself by installing twine on host, instead of inside the container, copying the built package from container to host directory, then uploading them using twine. The issue is resolved.